# Can we access "popular hours" on business pages from Facebook's API?

Tags: facebook, api

I'm building a web app for bars and restaurants and I see that Facebook has a great feature on business pages called "Popular Hours" that tells you how busy a place is and when.

Facebook's documentations doesn't seem to mention anything about it though. Does anyone know if that info is accessible via API?

p.s. Google has a similar feature called "Popular Times". It's currently being evaluated by the Google Maps team if it should be opened up. [https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8581]

Comment: Can you give the URL to an example page that shows those popular hours?

Comment: Here's a FB business page that has one.

https://www.facebook.com/churchkeydc/#

Best seen from desktop.

Comment: Interesting, never seen that before. Can't find anything about it in API docs or even FB help section either. My guess would be that it is based on checkins.